# Cryptography packafe installation error on google cloud ML

Tags: google-cloud-ml, python-packaging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g94fJ.png)

While running a job in google cloud ML, I have included few dependent packages in setup.py . While running the job, it gives the error that cryptography is not able to build_wheel. Cryptogrpahy could be a dependent package for one of the packages that i am trying to install. Please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your setup.py script to run arbitrary commands as part of installing your code; see this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168989/import-librosa-in-google-cloud-ml/42171824#42171824).

Comment: after trunning this self.RunCustomCommand , I am getting an error of no such file or directory found .

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Jeremy's answer a bit, a few lines after the screen shot, I see the following in the logs:

"Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path."

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22210069/1399222) answer indicates that the following needs to be run (based on [cryptography's documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux))

```
apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

Jeremy's answer contains a link to an example setup.py that runs `apt-get install` for `python-tk`. You should be able to follow the same approach with the following modification:

```
self.RunCustomCommand(
    ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'build-essential',
     'libssl-dev', 'libffi-dev', 'python-dev'])
```

Comment: this is still not working.. ERROR : not able to build_wheel for cryptography

Comment: Can you try running the apt-get command on your system or in a Docker container to see whether the supplied apt-get command works correctly? My guess the install process is trying to compile and build something and its failing.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it and it was because of the 'sudo' command, which I've removed from my post above. After removing sudo, things work correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Errors after submitting the setup.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60NiS.png)

Please see this link to check the log error file.