# Getting an error when trying to run my tensorflow code on the cloud

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying to get a tensorflow DNN code running on the gcloud. https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech

Currently I've succeeded with getting the the trainer to run locally using

```
gcloud ml-engine local train --module-name trainer.task --package-path trainer/
```

But it doesn't seem to be working when I try pushing it on the cloud

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH --runtime-version 1.0 --module-name trainer.task --package-path trainer/ --region $REGION
```

**The error arises in the logs at:**

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip-build-AWOKoy/cryptography/setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"
install --record /tmp/pip-bSegAw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-AWOKoy/cryptography/
```

> Module raised an exception for failing to call a subprocess Command '['pip', 'install', '--user', '--upgrade', '--force-reinstall', u'trainer-0.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Possible dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392866/cryptography-packafe-installation-error-on-google-cloud-ml/43421075#43421075

Comment: Yeah I copied everything that it said but...I'm still having the problem.                   INFO 2017-04-15 18:49:01 -0700 master-replica-0    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
INFO 2017-04-15 18:49:01 -0700 master-replica-0    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
INFO 2017-04-15 18:49:01 -0700 master-replica-0    No package 'libffi' found

Comment: @rhaertel80 Hey if you get the change could you take a look at my code https://github.com/varunravi/DeepSpeech I set my setup.py the way it is supposed to be setup but I can't get the problem to go away.

Comment: You have commented out the apt-get update. You need that in there. I manually ran the apt-get update, apt-get install, and used your setup.py and things seemingly work. Does it work for you (after uncommenting apt-get update in your setup.py)?